# Bash - lectura de fichero JSON y extracción de valores

Tags: json, bash

Estoy leyendo el json siguiente:

https://www.europarl.europa.eu/election-results-2019/data-sheets/json/2019-2024/election-results/parties.json

Quiero obtener una lista con los valores de 'countyId'.

Para ello, estoy haciendo lo siguiente:

```
curl -s "https://www.europarl.europa.eu/election-results-2019/data-sheets/json/2019-2024/election-results/parties.json" | jq.'countryId'
```

El error mostrado es:

```
jq.countyId: orden no encontrada
```

No entiendo que me indique este error ya que tengo jq instalado y puedo ver correctamente el json mediante la orden `curl -s ...`
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cómo puedo acceder a los valores?

Gracias.

Comment: te falta un espacio: en lugar de `jq.'countryId'`, debes decir `jq '.countryId'`. Es decir, `jq` como comando debe aparecer separado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que el objeto que requieres, esta inserto dentro de un arreglo llamado `countries`, simplemente lo debes referenciar y hacer la llamada.

```
curl -s "https://www.europarl.europa.eu/election-results-2019/data-sheets/json/2019-2024/election-results/parties.json" | jq '.countries[].countryId'
```

Saludos,